# Trying to import a SharedPreference of values?

Tags: android, gridview

I used SharedPreferences in one activity to basically store a bunch of data in a HashMap like method. In particular, app names (String) and their respective sorting as either a Category 1, 2, or 3 app. Stuff like:

editor.putString("Cut the Rope", "Category 1");

In another activity, I want to use this SharedPreference to create an ArrayList of only the Category 1 apps. Here is how I thought this could be done:

```
ArrayList<String> cat1Apps = new ArrayList<String>();
SharedPreferences stored = getSharedPreferences("Sorted Apps", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = stored.edit();
Map<String, ?> mappedPreferences = stored.getAll();

for(Map.Entry<String, ?> entry: mappedPreferences.entrySet()){
    if(entry.getValue().toString().equals("Category 1")){
        cat1Apps.add(entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

For some reason though, this isn't working. I'm taking these app names and then later there's some code that creates a GridView display of Category 1 apps. If I just define cat1Apps.add() a bunch of time, this works fine, but if I try to import through the SharedPreferences as above, it doesn't create the GridView.

Comment: Not really a solution but I'm pretty sure since SharedPreferences is key/value you can only ever have one value for key "Category 1" which in your case means that even if this does work you will only ever have a cat1Apps map of size 1 (where the value in the map is the last value saved).

Comment: Isn't it the other way around, a bunch of keys with value Category 1 is acceptable?

Comment: @scibor yes, without running it myself it looks like what you have should work. Have you set a breakpoint in there to see what values you get?

Comment: Slightly embarassing, how would I do that? Running in IntelliJ

Comment: Are you storing the values into the same shared preferences file, i.e. "Sorted Apps"? Is the retrieving Activity part of the same application as the storing one?

Comment: @codeMagic I got it, it turns out my error was that I forgot the line `editor.commit();` feel dumb. But still, if you could reference me to a good guide for debugging that would be good.

Comment: I didn't even think of that since you only showed that one line of putting it in. Good job figuring it out. I will try to find something quickly. In the meantime, you can post your solution as an answer to maybe help others

Comment: @scibor I added an answer with some links that should be helpful in debugging. I'm sure you can find plenty more even better links if you Google but these should at least get you started. I also posted your solution. Feel free to add and accept your own if you'd like

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `editor.commit()` was never inserted after after adding the `String`s to `SharedPreferences` so they were never saved. Otherwise, this code to retrieve the `SharedPreferences` was correct.

**Some debug links as asked for by the OP**

[This one isn't necessarily about debugging but has some good information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961049/effective-android-programming-techniques)

[Eclipse Debugging](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html)

[YouTube video onDebugging](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zt3RrmP2Xl0)- **Note** I just scrolled through some of this but looks like it could be helpful

Also not that when they say, "Right click and click toggle breakpoint", you can also double-click in the margin and you should see a green dot which means there's a breakpoint there. Double-click the green dot to remove the breakpoint.